# what does Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < mean?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

For this line of code :

```
var result = eval('('+result+')');
```

In this context:

```
function saveUser(){
    alert(url);
        $('#fm').form('submit',{
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(result){
                var result = eval('('+result+')');
                if (result.errorMsg){
                    $.messager.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: result.errorMsg
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#dlg').dialog('close');        // close the dialog
                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

How do i fix the error?

Comment: 1) eval is bad, 2) what is the content of `result`?

Comment: Hey Just check the code, Unexpected token, it will show you the line number where the error is occuring (Hope you are using Inspect element feature of your browser.)

Comment: Instead of `eval()`, you better use `JSON.parse()` :)

Answer (score 2):

> what does Uncaught SyntaxError ... mean?

It means that `eval` cannot parse the input (as JavaScript) because it contains a `<` where there shouldn't be one. FWIW if the response is HTML, `JSON.parse` wouldn't help either.

> How do i fix the error?

You either have to treat the response how it is expected to be treated, e.g. don't pass it through `eval` if it's HTML.

Or you fix the server side and return the repsonse that the client side expects, e.g. JSON.